# php list of all defined functions name contains or starts with specific string

Tags: php

I needed a list of all defined function which has a specific string in function name

Example : 
I want to get all the function in my file has `"special_pdf"` string in function name like -

```
special_pdf_a4()
special_pdf_a5()
special_pdf_16()
special_pdf_97()
special_pdf_same_same_example()
```

currently using this code -

```
$commandList = get_defined_functions();
$funcList = array();
$containText = 'special_pdf';
if(isset($commandList['user'])){
    $user_defined_functions = $commandList['user'];
    foreach($user_defined_functions as $user_defined_function){
        if(substr($user_defined_function, 0, strlen($containText)) === $containText){
            $funcList[] = $user_defined_function;
        }
    }
}
print_r($funcList);
```

is it a correct way to find out without performance drawback?

Answer (score 0):

Fast would probably be this solution

```
$funcs = get_defined_functions();
if(isset($funcs['user']) {
    funcList = preg_grep('/special_pdf.*/',$funcs['user']);
    print_r($funcList);
}
```

You maybe have to toy with the regex pattern a little bit, depending on your needs.